# Bash script countdown timer needs to detect any key to continue

Tags: bash

I need to listen for any key press in a countdown timer loop.  If any key is pressed then the countdown timer should break out of it's loop.  This mostly works except for the enter key just makes the countdown timer go faster.

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=30; i>0; i--)); do
    printf "\rStarting script in $i seconds.  Hit any key to continue."
    read -s -n 1 -t 1 key
    if [[ $key ]]
    then
        break
    fi
done
echo "Resume script"
```

I just can't seem to find any examples of how to detect that enter key anywhere online.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think based on the return code of `read`, there is a work around for this problem. From the `man` page of `read`,

```
The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out,
or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.
```

The return code for timeout seems to be `142` [verified in Fedora 16]

So, the script can be modified as,

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=30; i>0; i--)); do
    printf "\rStarting script in $i seconds.  Hit any key to continue."
    read -s -n 1 -t 1 key
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        break
    fi
done
echo "Resume script"
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks! I added a `read -t 0.01` to clear the keyboard buffer before the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `read` would *by default* consider a newline as a delimiter.

Set the `IFS` to null to avoid reading *upto* the delimiter.

Say:

```
IFS= read -s -N 1 -t 1 key
```

instead and you'd get the expected behavior upon hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key during the `read`.

Comment: Unfortunately this caused the same behavior I was getting.  The enter key would just continue to the next loop iteration.  I was looking at similar solutions to yours but I never found one.