# Bash press any key timer, skip to section

Tags: bash

I was reading this thread: [Bash script countdown timer needs to detect any key to continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251714/bash-script-countdown-timer-needs-to-detect-any-key-to-continue)

It seems I could implement something similar so that my script always starts out waiting x seconds for someone to hit a key. The thing I want to change is if they hit that key I want to skip to a specific part of my script.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (adapted from [Sakthi Kumar's answer in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21252715/52724)):

```
#!/bin/bash

was_key_pressed=

for (( i=10; i>0; i--)); do
    printf "\rHit any key to show 'Foo', or wait $i seconds and 'Bar' will be displayed..."
    read -s -n 1 -t 1 key
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        was_key_pressed="true"
        break
    fi
done
echo

if [ "${was_key_pressed}" ]; then
    echo "Foo"
else
    echo "Bar"
fi
```

The script uses a variable called `was_key_pressed`, and set's it's value to an empty string. Then, if a key is pressed in the `read` function, it sets the value of `was_key_pressed` to "true" and breaks out of the loop.

Once the loop has exited, the word "Foo" will be printed if a key was pressed by checking if `was_key_pressed` is still an empty string, otherwise "Bar" will be printed if no key was pressed.

Comment: I thought this was working as intended but it isn't and re-reading your explanation I think the problem is here: **otherwise both "Foo" and "Bar" will be printed.** where as I want only one or the other to be executed. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: @Tony - I've updated my answer based on your comment. Now "foo" will be executed if a key is pressed,  otherwise "bar" will be printed. Let me know if that's what you wanted :-)