# Bash Script: Pause a countdown and resume it by pressing ENTER (or any)

Tags: bash, shell, scheduled-tasks, git-bash

I have a task scheduler which runs a bash script. The task first opens a GIT Bash terminal, an opening message is shown ("The script is about to start in 60 seconds.") and runs a script at the end of that countdown.

Now, I would like to improve user experience, allowing him/her to stop/resume the countdown or (without any intervention) leaving the script running automatically. So, this is the procedure flow:

1. After the GIT Bash terminal open, allow the user to pause the script within the time frame shown by pressing ENTER or any other key;
2. If no action taken by user, the countdown continues and the script will run at the end of the timeframe;
3. If the user had pressed ENTER (or any other), then by pressing again ENTER (or any other key) he/she resumes the countdown and the will run immediately.

I've tried to use the `read -p` but it is not good for me: I don't want the user action to fire something but to stop/pause the countdown instead (and then resume it).

Answer (score 4):

Update history:

- A **Pausable Countdown** is implemented in the first part of the answer (prints lot of lines)
- A much less verbose **Pausable Timeout** is implemented in the second part (prints one static line + additional messages on key press)
- A somewhat more sophisticated **Pausable countdown that constantly updates the same line** is in the third code snippet.

---

**Pausable Countdown**

Combining some hints from similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251714/bash-script-countdown-timer-needs-to-detect-any-key-to-continue) and some external resources about how to read single character [(e.g. here, otherwise everywhere on the internet)](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-read-one-character-atatime-while-loop/), and adding an additional loop for resumption, this is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Starts a pausable/resumable countdown.
# 
# Starts the countdown that runs for the
# specified number of seconds. The 
# countdown can be paused and resumed by pressing the
# spacebar. 
#
# The countdown can be sped up by holding down any button
# that is no the space bar.
#
# Expects the number of seconds as single
# argument.
#
# @param $1 number of seconds for the countdown
function resumableCountdown() {
  local totalSeconds=$1
  while (( $totalSeconds > 0 ))
  do
    IFS= read -n1 -t 1 -p "Countdown $totalSeconds seconds (press <Space> to pause)" userKey
    echo ""
    if [ "$userKey" == " " ]
    then
      userKey=not_space
      while [ "$userKey" != " " ]
      do
        IFS= read -n1 -p "Paused, $totalSeconds seconds left (press <Space> to resume)" userKey
    echo ""
      done
    elif  [ -n "$userKey" ]
    then
      echo "You pressed '$userKey', press <Space> to pause!"
    fi
    totalSeconds=$((totalSeconds - 1))
  done
}

# little test
resumableCountdown 60
```

This can be saved and run as a stand-alone script. The function can be reused elsewhere. It pauses / resumes with `SPACE`, because this seemed to be more intuitive to me, because it's how it works e.g. in video-players embedded in browsers.

The countdown can also be sped up by pressing keys other than the space bar (that's a feature).

---

**Issuing a warning message and waiting for a pausable timeout**

The following variation implements a *pausable timeout*, which prints nothing but the initial warning message, unless the user pauses or resumes the (internal) countdown by pressing the spacebar:

```
# Prints a warning and then waits for a
# timeout. The timeout is pausable.
#
# If the user presses the spacebar, the 
# internal countdown for the timeout is 
# paused. It can be resumed by pressing
# spacebar once again.
#
# @param $1 timeout in seconds
# @param $2 warning message
warningWithPausableTimeout() {
  local remainingSeconds="$1"
  local warningMessage="$2"
  echo -n "$warningMessage $remainingSeconds seconds (Press <SPACE> to pause)"
  while (( "$remainingSeconds" > 0 ))
  do
    readStartSeconds="$SECONDS"
    pressedKey=""
    IFS= read -n1 -t "$remainingSeconds" pressedKey
    nowSeconds="$SECONDS"
    readSeconds=$(( nowSeconds - readStartSeconds ))
    remainingSeconds=$(( remainingSeconds - readSeconds ))
    if [ "$pressedKey" == " " ]
    then
      echo ""
      echo -n "Paused ($remainingSeconds seconds remaining, press <SPACE> to resume)"
      pressedKey=""
      while [ "$pressedKey" != " " ]
      do
        IFS= read -n1 pressedKey
      done
      echo ""
      echo "Resumed"
    fi
  done
  echo ""
}

warningWithPausableTimeout 10 "Program will end in"
echo "end."
```

---

**Pausable countdown that updates the same line**

This is a countdown similar to the first one, but it takes only a single line. Relies on `echo -e` for erasing and overriding previously printed messages.

```
# A pausable countdown that repeatedly updates the same line.
#
# Repeatedly prints the message, the remaining time, and the state of
# the countdown, overriding the previously printed messages.
#
# @param $1 number of seconds for the countdown
# @param $2 message
singleLinePausableCountdown() {
  local remainingSeconds="$1"
  local message="$2"
  local state="run"
  local stateMessage=""
  local pressedKey=""
  while (( $remainingSeconds > 0 ))
  do
    if [ "$state" == "run" ]
    then
      stateMessage="[$remainingSeconds sec] Running, press <SPACE> to pause"
    else
      stateMessage="[$remainingSeconds sec] Paused, press <SPACE> to continue"
    fi
    echo -n "$message $stateMessage"
    pressedKey=""
    if [ "$state" == "run" ]
    then 
      IFS= read -n1 -t 1 pressedKey
      if [ "$pressedKey" == " " ]
      then
        state="pause"
      else 
        remainingSeconds=$(( remainingSeconds - 1 ))
      fi
    else
      IFS= read -n1 pressedKey
      if [ "$pressedKey" == " " ]
      then
        state="run"
      fi
    fi
    echo -ne "\033[1K\r"
  done
  echo "$message [Done]"
}
```

This one might behave strangely if the line is longer than the console width (it does not erase the line completely).

---

Unsorted collection of hints for anyone who tries to make sth. similar:

- `IFS= read -n1` reads single character
- `read -t <seconds>` sets time-out for `read`. Once the timeout expires, `read` exits with non-zero, and sets variable to empty.
- Magic bash built-in variable `$SECONDS` measures the time from the start of the script in seconds.
- If a line has been printed with `echo -n`, then it can be erased and reset with `echo -ne "\033[1K\r"`.

Comment: Any reason `[ ! -z "$userKey" ]` can't be `[ -n "$userKey" ]`? or `[ ! "$userKey" == " " ]` be `[ "$userKey" != " " ]`? (nit: there is only one `=` in the string equality)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the hint, replaced `[ ! -z` by `[ -n`. There was no good reason, I simply remembered `-z` better, and didn't remember `-n`. Also merged some nested `if`s, they were unnecessary. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Also fixed the cumbersome string comparison. While I'm at it, I probably better go and look up what the proper syntax for documenting bash functions was... Thank you again, very helpful ;)

Comment: Bash is fairly flexible on function definitions either `name ()` or `function name [()]`, so you can get away with `function name` or `function name ()` in addition to the standard `name ()`.

Comment: It does not work as needed. Every second the script echoes "Countdown XX seconds...", I don't want that, I want an initial message appearing at terminal startup which advises the user that something will happen in the next 60 seconds.

Comment: Then it would be rather something like "issuing a 60-seconds warning with a pausable timeout" rather than a "countdown", because it wouldn't "count down". However, I updated the answer with a version that implements the pausable timeout.

Comment: @R99Photography I've added yet another solution. The third version is a countdown (it prints something every second when it's not paused), but it takes up only one line, because it repeatedly overrides the same line.